# How can I find out when a particular Google Streetview scene was shot?

Tags: google-maps, street-view

Looking at [scenic roads](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=San+Francisco,+CA,+United+States&daddr=37.646044,-118.964252&hl=en&ll=37.645625,-118.923052&spn=0.10833,0.264187&sll=37.661945,-118.975239&sspn=0.108306,0.264187&geocode=FVJmQAIdKAe0-CkhAGkAbZqFgDH_rXbwZxNQSg%3B&oq=san+fr&t=p&dirflg=r&ttype=dep&date=12%2F19%2F12&time=1:00am&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&mra=dme&mrsp=1&sz=13&z=13&layer=c&cbll=37.645625,-118.923052&panoid=PKPIf0n_AbwMhCTREKyCXw&cbp=12,138.95,,0,0.53&start=0), I think it would be quite interesting to know *when* the Google Streetview took the particular photo. In the linked example, it would give me an impression of possible snow conditions in a particular place at a certain time of the year.

Is it possible to find out the (approximate) date for which this scene was taken? If yes, how?

Comment: Because they are all-too-often used to hide spam and LMGTFY links. Further, they are unnecessary here since posts can contain several thousand characters. See also: [No URL Shorteners?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113658/21960) and [Ban URL shortening services](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64450/21960).

Comment: @AlE. I see the point about that they are unnecessary in this context (I admit I click on it semi-automatically when generating a Google Maps URL), but can Google Maps shortened URLs, that start with `goo.gl/maps`, really point to anything else than Google Maps?  If not, how could they hide spam on LMGTFY links?

Comment: You probably have a point there, but then why use a shortener here at all? It's not like you're going to run out of space.

Comment: I've updated the guidance at [URL shortener cleanup project](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2482/354)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a small little text saying "Image Date: March 2011" at the bottom of the street view (from the link you provided), though I can't confirm that it refers to the date the Street View image was taken, but its quite likely the case as there isn't any other images that it can refer to.

Hope this helps in getting an approximate date of when the image is taken, and it seems fairly accurate.

Answer (score 2):

As of April 2014, Street View

1. shows the image capture date at the bottom, e.g. `Image capture: Oct 2011`,
2. has a clock icon in the upper left-hand corner labeled like `Street View - Oct 2011`, and
3. if you click on the clock icon, lets you pick from the available capture dates.

See [Go back in time with Street View](https://maps.googleblog.com/2014/04/go-back-in-time-with-street-view.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check the top left corner of a Street View scene:

> Street View - Oct 2017

As well as the bottom left corner:

> Image capture: Oct 2017

[image: Google Street View Date]

Answer (score -2):

In street view, go to a site that has a marquee that gives the date, maybe a bank or gas station.

Comment: This won't help to find the date of a "particular photo". It's unlikely that "a bank or gas station" will be located nearby.